Running Concurrent Asynchronous Requests Efficiently using Refinitiv's Data Platform APIs
This question is kind of me seeking advice on this process based off of my knowledge.
What I am doing right now, is that I am trying to pull data asyncrhonously using Refinitiv (financial Platform from the London Stock Exchange Group)'s APIs. There are about 5 tasks I am trying to run asynchronously using Python's Async IO package, all calling one function with a differing value I am putting in the parameters each time, like so:
For context, each task is to run 503 times, and each Refinitiv API call is pulling a Pandas Dataframe with Data for the last 8 years (so 8 rows a request). Now, here are issues I am facing:

I get the too many requests error when I try and gather tasks (asyncio.gather), and I get a lot of missing data. So much so, that I included a semaphore , for which I lowered the value down to 2, and I STILL get that error when running the code exerpt above. I get that it isn't about the total number of requests you have, but how you send them. In my case, I am sending too many at one time apparently.

It takes really long for the data to come. To get full, accurate data, I have to rely on using a semaphore to run Refinitiv's API 503 times in 1 task, and that takes 10 minutes. I need to find a way to run this API call for multiple stocks quickly, where I am not sending TOO many requests, and I need to be able to somehow manage this in an efficient manner, so that I don't get the data in SUCH a long time. Because, I don't think, that per task (where there are 5 of them), it should be quick to get back my data


(Side note, I have some functions and data processing when I receive my data to clean it (remove any void, invalid data from the dataframes I am receiving)
This is some code illustration to show some of what I am talking about:
tasks = [
    main([3 Fields passed]),
    main([3 Fields passed]),
    main([3 Fields passed]),
    main([2 Fields passed]),
    main([[2 Fields passed]),
];

and inside that function,
# fetch_fundamental_data has the refinitiv API Call
tasks = [fetch_fundamental_data(ticker, semaphore) for index, ticker in enumerate(tickers)]
results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # Await all tasks, handle exceptions properly

is the API call that basically retrieves the data
response = await content.fundamental_and_reference.Definition(
                universe=[f'{ric}'],
                fields=specific_fields,
                parameters={"SDate": f"{start_year + 1}-01-01", "EDate": f"{current_year}-12-31", "Frq": "Y"}
            ).get_data_async(closure='');

(Note that these fields are passed to the Refinitiv API. The main() function includes a call of the API, and then, some processing logic for the data I receive. This is data for different datapoints for the stocks of the SNP 500.)
If anyone has a strategy that I can employ based on my situation, feel free to let me know. (Side Question, is there a sub-event loop created for nested asynchronous operations occurring inside existing asynchronous tasks?)
Thanks!!!
